# Laravel: a simple MVC example

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and the documentation's basic task list returns Views from the Route(`web.php`) but I want to use a Controller to return an image file.

So I have for my route:

```
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index');
```

Then my ProductController action (please ignore comments as I'm using `index` to simplify things):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     Fetch and return all product records.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        //return response()->json(Product::all(), 200);
        return view('/pages/product', compact('product'));

    }
```

And my product.blade.php (nested in views/pages/product):

```
<img src="/images/product/Frozen_Ophelia_800x.png">
```

I keep getting a ReflectionException Class App\Product does not exist.

I got this working when I just returned a view from the route.  I'm getting a `ReflectionException
Class App\Product does not exist` so I think it's something at the top, ie. `use App\Product;` that is wrong.

Edit (below is my `App\Product` nested in `app/Providers`):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'units', 'description', 'image'
    ];

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: if still shows you the error `Class App\Product does not exist`, make sure of the model name and that it exists, and the file name usually should be `Product.php`, and also run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `App\Product` model exists, correct code should be:

```
public function index() {
    $product = Product::all();
    return view('pages.product', compact('product'));
}
```

Check [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views).

PS did you call a `$ composer dumpautoload`? `ReflectionException Class` error is often related to new class autoloading (eg. new classes in a packages)

Comment: I just did a `composer dumpautoload` and it worked right away!

Answer (score 1):

view function should have any view template not any url or route. Of you have file `views/pages/product.blade.php` then use

```
   view('pages.product',compact('product'));
```

Comment: Yes, I added in my edit but it's nested in folder `/Providers` so is it use `App\Providers\Product`?